# Retirar espaços em branco de uma string

Tags: c++, string

Quero retirar todos os espaços em branco de uma *string*, mas não sei como fazer já tentei usar `replace` mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem [algoritmo pronto na biblioteca](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) que facilita muito o trabalho:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = " texto com espaços em branco ";
    str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
    cout << str;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/r6sp3b). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dlfspusn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/RemoveSpaces.cpp).

Comment: Funcionou!! estava já a um tempo tentando, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Contribuindo para esse tema fiz uma mesclagem de C/C++, objetivando retirar os espaços excedentes, tanto no final quanto no meio de uma string.
Veja o código que consegui

```
string RemoveEspaco(string str)
{
int i, j;
char *input, *out;
string output;

input = new char[str.length()+1];
strcpy(input,str.c_str());

for (i=strlen(input); i > 0; i--)
    {
    if (input[i] != ' ')
        {
        break;
        }
    }
input[i] = '\0';
out = new char[strlen(input)+1];
for (i=0,j=0;i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
    if (i > 1)
        {
        if (input[i] != ' ')
            {
            out[j] = input[i];
            j++;
            }
        else
            {
            if ((input[i] == ' ')&&(input[i-1] != ' '))
                {
                out[j] = input[i];
                j++;
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        out[j] = input[i];
        j++;
        }
    }
out[j] = '\0';
output.clear();
output.append(out);

return(output);
}
```